# How can I prove $P\land(Q\land R)$ from $\lnot[P\rightarrow\lnot (Q\land R)]?$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have been asked to prove $P\land(Q\land R)$ from the premises $\lnot[P\rightarrow\lnot (Q\land R)]$.

Could someone please point me in the right direction to solve this question, or a question like it?

Premise: $\lnot[P\rightarrow\lnot (Q\land R)]$

Conclusion : $P\land(Q\land R)$

Comment: All caps is considered the internet equivalent to shouting. Why are you shouting at us?

Comment: Correct your mistakes in the problem statement.

Comment: I don't know which rules you are allowed to use, I can give you a derivation (or an advice) using natural deduction rules. That would help you?

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $A\rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg A\vee B$.

$$\neg[P\rightarrow \neg(Q\wedge R)]\equiv \neg[\neg P\vee \neg(Q\wedge R)]$$

Upon distributing the negation, we obtain $$\neg\neg P\wedge\neg\neg(Q\wedge R) $$ which is equivalent to $$P\wedge(Q\wedge R) $$

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: @dsnr YOU'RE WELCOME!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the definition of $A\rightarrow B$, which is $\lnot A\lor B$.  Also consider de Morgans law, $\lnot(A\lor B)=\lnot A\land\lnot B$. Together, you can use these rules to show that $\lnot(A\rightarrow B)$ is $A\land\lnot B$.

Are you able to solve the question using these two rules?

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: @dsnr No problem.